# Javascript time string to date

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a time as a string like "10:00pm" and I need to convert it into a date object so it can be represented in an input type="time" tag.  Im using angularjs to model it.

I get an error saying "Expected `10:00am` to be a date".  How can I convert "10:00am" into a date object? I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

I only need the time

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: 10:00am will need a day, month and year to become a date

Comment: I don't need the date. only the time

Comment: if you have already loaded moment, i would use that.

Comment: hmmm maybe I shouldn't use an input type="time" tag

Comment: see http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: @A_Arnold Thank you this worked very nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [date.js](http://datejs.com) then you could try

```
Date.parseExact("10:00 PM", "hh:mm tt");
```

This should also pick up if you've loaded the library correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://momentjs.com/ ?

You can use it like this:

```
var time = moment("10:00pm", "HH:mm a");
```

Comment: +1 if you have already loaded Moment, I would use Moment for any date manipulation, it's just safer that way.